# How can I destroy an Activity from a static method?

Tags: java, android

I have a subclass `checkLoginTask` in my Activity `LoginActivity` (this activity is for the login of a user) . This subclass is called from in the onPostExecute() from a class that extends AsynTask.

I want to destroy the activity `LoginActivty` if `theLoginOk == "ok"` and start the activity  `MainActivity`. I used `finish()` but I got a error  `Non-Static method "finish()" cannot be referenced from a static context`

I tried with `final Activity activity = this;` but does not worked.

this is the method on my Avtivity `LoingPage`

```
public static void checkLoginTrue(JSONObject jsonObject, Context context){
    if(jsonObject != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        try {
            JSONObject student = jsonObject.getJSONObject("status");
            String theId = student.getString("id");
            String theLoginOk = student.getString("login");

            Log.i("JSON login", theLoginOk);

            if (theLoginOk.equals("ok")) {
                intent.putExtra("id", theId);
                intent.putExtra("login", theLoginOk);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // something
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post the complete activity code?

Comment: Why is this method static?  If its only static so you can call it from an AsyncTask elsewhere, you're doing things wrong and should use a callback interface to inform the Activity the login is complete.

Comment: In practice, you would send a message back to the parent context with instructions.  So, for example, you can use `startActictyForResult`, and have the `onReceive` callback finish the `Activity`

Comment: I think I should use callback interface (I did not know that). I am new in this and I have a lot of question but your answers give me something that I need to know. You know a good tutorial or something to learn about callback in android? Thanks for your time and your answers

Answer (score 1):

here no need for static method. if you want practice for calling static method in activity class, Create onr Util class in that create static methods and call from activity override methods.
like

```
public class Utill
{

   public static void checkLoginTrue(JSONObject jsonObject, Context context, Class<? extends Activity> myClass){
        if(jsonObject != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, myClass);

            try {
                JSONObject student = jsonObject.getJSONObject("status");
                String theId = student.getString("id");
                String theLoginOk = student.getString("login");

                Log.i("JSON login", theLoginOk);

                if (theLoginOk.equals("ok")) {
                    intent.putExtra("id", theId);
                    intent.putExtra("login", theLoginOk);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // something
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then call

```
 Utils.checkLoginTrue(jsonObject, this, MainActivity.class);
```

in your activity any override  non-static and/or static method.

Answer (score 1):

Use Broadcast receiver to finish activity or eventbus to avoid leaks in memory, singletons should not exists in android!

Example:

```
public class FinishableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String ACTION_FINISH = FinishableActivity.class.getName() + ".FINISH";
    public static final String EXTRA_ACTIVITY_CLASS = "EXTRA_ACTIVITY_CLASS";

    private FinishBroadcastListener finishReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        finishReceiver = new FinishBroadcastListener()
                .register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        finishReceiver.unregister(this);
        finishReceiver = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void show(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> cls) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, cls) {{
            addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        }});
    }

    public static void hide(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> cls) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH) {{
            putExtra(EXTRA_ACTIVITY_CLASS, cls);
        }});
    }

    class FinishBroadcastListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = (intent == null) ? "" : intent.getAction();
            action = (action == null) ? "" : action;

            if (ACTION_FINISH.contentEquals(action)) {
                onFinishCalled((Class<? extends Activity>) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_ACTIVITY_CLASS));
            }
        }

        public FinishBroadcastListener register(Context context) {
            context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH));

            return this;
        }

        public void unregister(Context context) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    }

    private void onFinishCalled(Class<? extends Activity> cls) {
        if (cls == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            if (cls.equals(getClass())) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `finish()` didn't work when you tried because you need an actual activity object to call it on. Static methods do not run on objects. Thats why they can't use `this`.

You must pass your activity object reference to the static method and then `finish()` it. If you have already passed it as `Context context` then cast it to activity first. Example:

```
//if your context is actually activity reference, use line below
//if not, add another Activity argument to the method
//if you cant get to the activity to pass it as argument, save it in a static reference somewhere, during ocCreate for example, and you can access it globally
Activity activity = (Activity) context;

//correct way to use finish()
activity.finish();
```